# Is there a way to observe the content offset of a scrolling SwiftUI Chart?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, charts, swiftui-charts

I need to create a component which enables the users to select a value in a specific date by horizontally scrolling the SwiftUI charts. The image of the component is below.

[image]

My code block is as below:

```
struct SampleModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var date: String
    var value: Double
    var animate: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var data = [
        SampleModel(date: "26\nFr", value: 9.2),
        SampleModel(date: "27\nSa", value: 12.5),
        SampleModel(date: "28\nSu", value: 15.0),
        SampleModel(date: "29\nMo", value: 20.0),
        SampleModel(date: "30\nTu", value: 5.0),
        SampleModel(date: "31\nWe", value: 7.0),
        SampleModel(date: "01\nTh", value: 3.0),
        SampleModel(date: "02\nFr", value: 20.0),
        SampleModel(date: "03\nSa", value: 5.0),
        SampleModel(date: "04\nSu", value: 7.0),
        SampleModel(date: "05\nMo", value: 3.0),
        SampleModel(date: "06\nTu", value: 10.0),
        SampleModel(date: "07\nWe", value: 21.0),
        SampleModel(date: "08\nTh", value: 14.0),
        SampleModel(date: "09\nFr", value: 10.0),
        SampleModel(date: "10\nSt", value: 7.0),
        SampleModel(date: "11\nSu", value: 15.0),
        SampleModel(date: "12\nMo", value: 17.0),
        SampleModel(date: "13\nTu", value: 29.0)
    ]
    @State private var scrollPosition: String = "26\nFr"
    @State var priceText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Text(priceText)
                    .padding()

                Chart(data) { flight in
                    BarMark(x: .value("Date", flight.date),
                            y: .value("Price", flight.value),
                            width: 10.0)
                    .foregroundStyle(
                        Gradient(
                            colors: [
                                .blue,
                                .green
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
                }
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 180)
                .background(content: {
                    VStack {
                        Color.gray.frame(width: 1)
                        Color.clear.frame(height: 40)
                    }
                })
                .chartXAxis(content: {
                    AxisMarks(preset: .extended, position: .bottom) { value in
                        let label = value.as(String.self)!
                        AxisValueLabel(label)
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    }
                })
                .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
                .chartXVisibleDomain(length: 11)
                .chartYAxis(.hidden)
                .chartScrollTargetBehavior(
                    .valueAligned(unit: 1)
                )
                .chartOverlay { proxy in
                    
                }
            }
            .frame(width: .infinity)

        }
    }
}
```

I need to observe the content offset of the horizontally scrolling chart in order to retrieve the centre value based on the position by using `proxy` of `chartOverlay`. Is there a way to observe the content offset of the scrolling chart? Or is there another perspective to retrieve the centre value in the scrolling chart?

Comment: This design is flawed in the first place. Users would not be able to select the first 5 and last 5 dates.

Comment: There will be more days before and after the range to prevent this case from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your approach,
I added some improvements, I added margin on the left and right side, allowing a proper selection when scrolling, also defined a scrollPosition which is `Int` to track the index selected of your data.

If you want to change the value shown on top you only need to modify the `selectionText` function to return `.value` if you need

hope this is what you are asking for.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct SampleModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var date: String
    var value: Double
    var animate: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var data = [
        SampleModel(date: "26\nFr", value: 9.2),
        SampleModel(date: "27\nSa", value: 12.5),
        SampleModel(date: "28\nSu", value: 15.0),
        SampleModel(date: "29\nMo", value: 20.0),
        SampleModel(date: "30\nTu", value: 5.0),
        SampleModel(date: "31\nWe", value: 7.0),
        SampleModel(date: "01\nTh", value: 3.0),
        SampleModel(date: "02\nFr", value: 20.0),
        SampleModel(date: "03\nSa", value: 5.0),
        SampleModel(date: "04\nSu", value: 7.0),
        SampleModel(date: "05\nMo", value: 3.0),
        SampleModel(date: "06\nTu", value: 10.0),
        SampleModel(date: "07\nWe", value: 21.0),
        SampleModel(date: "08\nTh", value: 14.0),
        SampleModel(date: "09\nFr", value: 10.0),
        SampleModel(date: "10\nSt", value: 7.0),
        SampleModel(date: "11\nSu", value: 15.0),
        SampleModel(date: "12\nMo", value: 17.0),
        SampleModel(date: "13\nTu", value: 29.0)
    ]
    @State private var scrollPosition: Int = 0
    @State var priceText: String? = nil
    @State var selectedIndex: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                if let price = priceText {
                    Text(price)
                        .padding()
                }

                    Text(selectionText())
                        .padding()

                Chart(Array(zip(data.indices, data)), id: \.0) { index, flight in
                    BarMark(x: .value("Index", index),
                            y: .value("Price", flight.value), width: .fixed(10))
                    .foregroundStyle(
                        Gradient(
                            colors: [
                                .blue,
                                .green
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
                }
                .frame(height: 180)
                .background(content: {
                    VStack {
                        Color.gray.frame(width: 1)
                        Color.clear.frame(height: 40)
                    }
                })
                .chartXAxis(content: {
                    AxisMarks(preset: .aligned, position: .bottom, values: .stride(by: 1)) { value in
                        let label = data[value.index].date
                        AxisValueLabel(label)
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    }
                })
                .chartXVisibleDomain(length: 10)
                .chartYAxis(.hidden)
                .chartScrollTargetBehavior(
                    .valueAligned(unit: 1)
                )
                .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
                .chartScrollPosition(x: $scrollPosition)
                .contentMargins(Edge.Set(arrayLiteral: [.leading, .trailing]), geometry.size.width/2)
            }
        }
    }

    private func selectionText() -> String {
        guard scrollPosition >= .zero else {
            return data[.zero].date
        }

        guard scrollPosition < data.count else {
            return data[data.count - 1].date
        }

        return data[scrollPosition].date
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be in the right path. The guy was asking for the scroll offset. Maybe multiplying the scrollPosition by their width could do the trick?

Comment: Actually Is what I am doing in $scrollPosition variable @MatBuompy

Comment: I did not know it worked that way, good.

Comment: I wanted to retrieve the corresponding value by calculating the position of the centre element within the scrolling chart. However, your solution is simple and it works great.